# Which website was Donald Trump mentioning in his speech declaring his candidacy for the 2016 election?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

In the speech where Donald Trump was declaring his participation in the election, he mentioned a website which is worth 5 billion USD. But which website was he actually mentioning? [Here](https://youtu.be/OCabT_O0YSM?t=20m48s) is the YouTube link of his speech.  Starting with the relevant [quote](https://youtu.be/q_q61B-DyPk?t=14m).

Comment: At what time in the video is this?  What does it sound like he was saying?  What was the context?

Comment: I have edited the youtube link

Comment: @Brythan please check this link https://youtu.be/q_q61B-DyPk?t=14m

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that this [fact check](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2015/jul/14/donald-trump/donald-trump-says-5-billion-website-obamacare-neve/) covers that speech (or a similar one).

> He singled out the healthcare.gov website, which was unveiled in the fall of 2013 with a panoply of bugs and glitches, calling it "the $5 billion website for Obamacare, which never worked. Still doesn't work."

Assuming that that is the right speech, then the website is healthcare.gov and the $5 billion number is disputed.  The Obama administration claims $834 million.  The fact check claims that the number is around the range of $1 billion to $2 billion.